# Excel 2013 if statement with multiple and statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I've been looking at other examples but I'm not sure how to apply them. I've gone through some trial and error and either get "Yes" when I know I shouldn't (not all four fields have the prerequisite "Yes" in them) or I get an error message. The code I have is just for U4 and V4 but I would like to make it for four cells (W4 and X4, also).

Essentially,

```
    =IF(U4="Yes" AND  (V4 ="Yes"), "Complete", "No")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the `AND` immediately after the `IF` and then all conditions as:

```
=IF(AND(U4="Yes", V4 ="Yes"), "Complete", "No")
```

Comment: @User15, I've given up posting answers for new users who don't have the Informed badge. They rarely bother to pay the courtesy of accepting an answer.